# Can the 57-cell be made in vZome without strut crossings?

Tags: graph-theory, open-problem

Here's the [57-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57-cell) in [vZome](http://vzome.com/) with lots of strut crossings:

[image: 57-cell in vZome]

Is it possible to construct the 57-cell in vZome without any strut crossings? That is, 57 nodes, 171 struts, in the 57-cell / Perkel graph configuration, with no struts going through other struts or clipping nodes?

A Mathematica version is at [57-cell](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The57Cell/). The vZome version is at [57cell.vZome](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/57cell.vZome).

I'll pay $57 for the first solution with no trickery of any kind. All of the strut-types currently defined in vZome are allowable.

Comment: Surely just making the nodes and struts thin enough and randomly moving the nodes around a little ought to yield a solution.  Of course, that's sort of a cheap trick, in the sense that the result won't have any kind of elegant symmetry and won't be much help in, say, constructing a nice-looking physical model.

Comment: Zome is based on Phi-space, where all coordinates are triples of the form  $a + b\phi $. With 57 nodes and the restriction to defined vZome directions, there are only a finite (but huge) number of available lattice points, and randomly moving the nodes won't work.